# Deleting a chlid object from a collection with MVC3 Entity Framework 4.3 Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have found numerous posts with very similar problems as mine, but they all seem to use a `DeleteObject()` method that doesnt appear to exist in the version of EF i am using! (although its more than likely i am looking in the wrong places)

Anyway, my problem. I have two classes, `User` and `Email` where a user can have many emails. I have an edit form that will quite happily allow me to edit all email addresses attached to each user. I would like to allow each email address to be deleted simply by clearing the text box in the edit form (to be done using JavaScript function triggered by a remove button associated with each box later on). To this end, when the data is posted back, I loop through all the email addresses and test if the address property is null, at which point i want to delete that `Email` object completely. Below is my edit controller that is (not) doing the business:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, User User)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Email Email in User.Emails)
        {
            if (Email.Address == null)
            {
                User.Emails.Remove(Email);
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(Email).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        db.Entry(User).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This works to a point, using the debugger i can see that it is quite happily removing the `Email` object from the `User`, but as soon as it has done that once it will throw an exception when it tries to go through the loop again:

`Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

my question: what is the correct method of deleting the `Email` object, not only from the `User`, but from my db too?

Thanks in advance ;-)

**EDIT:**

I have modified my controller to create two lists, one for `Emails` with and address and one for those where the address is null, and loop through those instead:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, User User)
{
    try
    {
        var notNullEmails = User.Emails.Where(e => e.Address != null).ToList();
        foreach (Email Email in notNullEmails)
        {
            db.Entry(Email).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        var isNullEmails = User.Emails.Where(e => e.Address == null).ToList();
        foreach (Email Email in isNullEmails)
        {
            db.Emails.Remove(Email);
        }
        db.Entry(User).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

But that resulted in this exception:

`Message=The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.`

So i adapted the `foreach` used for the null addresses to explicitly pull the email to be deleted into the context like so:

```
var isNullEmails = User.Emails.Where(e => e.Address == null).ToList();
foreach (Email Email in isNullEmails)
{
    Email EmailToDelete = db.Emails.Find(Email.Id);
    db.Emails.Remove(EmailToDelete);
}
```

But that results in this exception:

`Message=Value cannot be null.`

I think i am getting there thanks to you guys, but i could use a little more help please :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is really old, but i thought i should probably answer it with the method i have found to actually work:

```
foreach(Email email in User.Emails)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Address))
    {
        db.Entry(email).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

I think this is the simplest of any solution that i have seen so far, but feel free to correct me if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different problems:

One is, you can't remove items from a collection as you iterate the collection. Iterate through a List copy uoi make with .ToList() instead.

The other is, calling the Remove() method you are calling is only removing the relationship to the User - not actually removing it from the database. This would generate a referential integrity error, if the db enforces it.

Instead, You want to call Remove on the Emails DbSet.

```
context.emails.Remove(email);
```

Remove() is the method used by the DbContext. DeleteObject and RemoveObject are older/alternative APIs

Comment: Thanks! It seems a bit weird that i should have to copy them to a list, but so be it if thats the way! Having implemented your suggestion i am again stuck, would you mind casting your eye over the edit to the question? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you said about not using DeleteObject, but I had the same problem and thought I should post the answer here for others searching about this issue:

---

```
int i = User.Emails.Count - 1;
while (true)
{
  if (i<0)
  {
     break;
  }
  Db.Emails.DeleteObject(User.Emails.ElementAt<Email>(i));
  i--;
}
```

Comment: whoa i forgot about this question. I am now a bit more comfortable with c# and ef, so i'll answer my own question in a minute